# Svn in PhpStorm, how can I update single files?

Tags: svn, phpstorm

So far I only see a "Update whole project" button.

In the changes view, I see the "Incoming" tab, and I can browse all the different changes that have been committed, but how can I update single files (like in Eclipse) and not all project at once?

For example:

Someone checks in File A and File B. I want to see the changes made in them but only "download" (update) changes made in File A.

Is this possible in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 and 2, Click on the target revision (Incoming tab of the Changes view), navigate to the file (on the right), and right-click it.

1. You can then select "Diff with Local" to compare the local version of your file to the commit.

   - This allows you to selectively update your version with what is currently committed
2. You can also select "Open Repository Version" to open a read-only version of the file, as it's currently committed to the repository.

   - This allows you to copy/paste the entire contents to your local file
3. You can also go to the Project navigator, right-click on your target file, and select Subversion > Update File.

   - You should select which revision number you want to update to (Update/Switch to specific revision).
   - Click [Ok]